# Ordering Subcategories

Tags: order

I'm using the following code to display data from subcategories. The subcategories are 'United kingdom', 'England Only', 'Northern Ireland Only', 'Scotland Only', 'Wales Only'.

Ordering by date or asc/desc puts the UK subcategory somewhere in the middle with either Wales or England at the top. I need the UK subcategory to be at the top. It holds the most posts - so is it possible to use an orderby in the query to fix this? Or do you think I need to create its own loop for the UK subcategory only?

```
$parentCatID = get_cat_ID('Grants and Incentives');
$childCats = get_categories( 'child_of='.$parentCatID.'&orderby=date&order=asc' );
if(is_array($childCats)):
foreach($childCats as $child){ ?>
<h2 class="experts <?php echo $child->name; ?>"><?php echo $child->name; ?> Grants and Incentives</h2>
<?php query_posts('cat='.$child->term_id.'&post_type=grants-and-incentive');
while(have_posts()): the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
```

Edit: I'm now using the [Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) and **orderby=term_order**. Which works great. It would be good to know how this works without using a plugin though, if anyone could explain it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the plugin you found but it looks pretty heavy, at least on the backend, and may be overkill unless you need a lot more functionality than described in the question.

`get_categories` operates from [cached data](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1243) so my thought was to simple alter the returned array rather than perform another query or a more complicated one.

```
function move_cat_to_top_wpse_107314($move, $cats = array()) {
  if (empty($move) || empty($cats)) {
    return false;
  }
  $cat = array_search($move,wp_list_pluck($cats,'slug'));
  if (false !== $cat) {
    $tmp = $cats[$cat];
    unset($cats[$cat]);
    array_unshift($cats,$tmp);
  }
  return $cats;
}

$parent = get_cat_ID('aciform');
$children = get_categories( 
  array( 
    'child_of' => $parent,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'asc',
  )
);
// var_dump($children);
var_dump(move_cat_to_top_wpse_107314('sub', $children));
```

The `move_cat_to_top_wpse_107314` function is all you need. The rest illustrates usage and works with data on my sandbox site.

Also, [please don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/21376).